# Acumatica REST API - how to link multiple contacts with one customer

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am able to create one customer and one contact separately.
But not able to link one contact created with the new customer being created or updated.

can some one help me with sample json request for creating one new customer where in we must be able to mention the contact id already created.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Business Account is the field to use in order to link a Contact to a Customer. You need to set that field to be equal to the CustomerID of the customer you want to link to that contact.

Here is the request that I did once the customer was created and I had the ID

PUT : localhost/demo182u10/entity/Default/18.200.001/Contact

```
{
    "BusinessAccount": {"value": "ABARTENDE"},
    "ContactID": {"value": 9977}
}
```

Tough this can also be done at the creation of the Contact using the same field

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked once we added BusinessAccount to our custom endpoint url.